# Unable to recognize Element with relative xpath or other locator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am facing an issue where I am unable to locate Element on webpage with any type of locator expect Absolute xpath. Here are details:

URL : https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#selection

Required Element Screen shot:
[image]

Manually created Xpath Screen shot( **Please note that I am able to recognize Element in web application with manually created xpath but Same xpath is not working in selenium code**)
[image: Element Screen shot]

But Same xpath is not working in selenium script.[image: Selenium Script]

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM ABLE TO IDENTIFY SAME OBJECT WITH Absolute xpath**
Please help to me to understand reason for this.

Here is code:

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html");

    //Selection
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui selection dropdown upward']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='menu transition visible']/div[text()='Female']")).click();

    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Ohh Sorry. I forgot to add Code line. I shared screen shot for clear image of Element which I am working. Do I need to update question>?

Comment: Have you checked whether that element is not inside the frame ...? 
 Could you please provide the Absolute xpath ..?

Comment: Thanks for reply but Object is in normal frame. Issue is resolved by Murthi's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be issue with your first x-path. You may try the following code. It may work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui selection dropdown']").click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='menu transition visible']/div[text()='Male']").click();
```

Comment: I have written same one. Please refer code which I shared.Thanks for comment

Comment: The xpaht is different, please check. I am not able to find class upward in that.  //div[@class='ui selection dropdown']"

Comment: Perfect answer but Please explain me that why did U omit class Upward in that?

Comment: upward is not there in my chrome browser and it is visible only if we do some actions.

Comment: Oh Yes. Even i just noticed by opening URL in fresh browser. Class Upward is getting added after first click and remain added through out browser session. I am surprised to see such behavior of DOM details of an object. Is it bcoz of element is CSS enabled rather than HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168173/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-murthi).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a preceding wildcard in you driver.FindElement XPath.

Instead of `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div..."));`, do `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*div..."));`.

Currently, what your code is doing is telling the XPath locator to find a first level div (not easily possible, as the first item is almost always the document body), but the wildcard of "*" tells it that it can look for the div at any level.

As an aside, please edit your answer up top with actual code instead of pictures so others with the same problem can find their solution easier.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried same way but now it is saying that given xpath is INVALIDSELECTOREXCEPTION. Here is path which I created after Ur suggestion: //*div[@class='ui selection dropdown upward']

Comment: This is invalid selector. The wildcard means any type of element - if you use it like this: By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'share-layout-header')]), it will look for any element type that has this class - div, h1,h2,h3 or any other element.

Answer (score 0):

**Longshot:**

You are using Chrome to look at the source, but Selenium is using Firefox.

There is a chance that the source is rendered differently between the two browsers. Specifically, your xpath is relying on an exact match of class. I do know that FireFox is notorious for modifying source output.

I haven't done any testing but I would not be surprised if the class is in a different order and it's failing on an exact match.

There are two solutions if that is the case:

1. Don't do a single exact match (xpath = "") but instead do a mix of contains joined with && (contains ui && contains selection && dropdown)
2. Don't rely on the output from the console tab. Instead "View Page Source" and view what is actually being sent instead of what is being interpreted by the browser

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using chrome just to read Xpath as it is easy there than Firefox. i am executing Script in Firefox as I am getting some know errors in chrome when using Selenium 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Find the dropdown container element firstly, then use it to find self descendant, like option etc.

```
driver.get("https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html");

// find dropdown container element
WebElement dropdownWrapper = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='html']/div[input[@name='gender']]"));

// expand drop down options by click on the container element
dropdownWrapper.click();
// or click the down arrow
dropdownWrapper.findElement(By.css('i')).click();

// select option
dropdownWrapper.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[text()='Female']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **Gender** and select the option **Female** you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

Code Block :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#selection");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='another dropdown example']//div[@class='ui dropdown selection']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='another dropdown example']//div[@class='ui dropdown selection active visible']//div[@class='menu transition visible']//div[@class='item' and contains(.,'Female')]")).click();
System.out.println("Gender Female selected.");
```

Console Output :

```
Gender Female selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to clearify how selectors are working in general:

1. .(dot): Dot at starting represents the current node. It tells us that the processing will start from the current node.
2. . .(double dot): It will select parent of current node. For example, //table/. . will return div element because div is the parent of table element.
3. ‘*’: is used to select all the element nodes descending from the current node. For example:

/table/*:  It will select all child elements of a table element.

//*: It will select all elements in the document.

//*[@id = ‘username’]: It will select any element in document which has an attribute named “id” with the specified value “username”.

4. @:  It represents an attribute which selects id, name, className, etc. For example:

@id: It will select all elements that are defined with the id attribute in the document. No matter where it is defined in the document.
//img/@alt: It will select all the img elements that are defined with the @alt attribute.
//td[@*]: It will select all td elements with any attribute.

Here is a link to the article:
https://www.scientecheasy.com/2020/07/selenium-xpath-example.html/